# Find Maximum across columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with 4 columns SID, Physics, Chemistry, Math. I need to get SID and maximum marks irrespective of the Subject, can anyone help me please.

For Eg

```
SID Physics Chemistry Maths
1      25      30       85
2      45      28       91
3      97      40       76
```

Output

```
SID  Max_Marks 
3     97
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support `least()` and `greatest()`.  So, you can do something like this:

```
select sid, greatest(Physics, Chemistry, Maths) as max_marks
from t
order by max_marks desc
limit 1;
```

This syntax is more suitable for MySQL.  However, you can do something similar in almost any database.